# Impossible to make object with a recursive type constraint?

Tags: types, f#, type-constraints, recursive-type

This is a purely academic question, but riffing off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544976/order-of-type-constraints-in-f)
about type constraints. The questioner gave this as an example:

```
type Something<'a, 'b when 'b :> seq<'b>>() =
    member __.x = 42
```

which f# happily compiles.  Now the problem is how do you make this object??

```
let z = new Something<???, ???>()
```

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.openxmlelement(v=office.14).aspx for a non-contrived example of a class that could be used.

Comment: Maybe you should change the title to remove the word `Impossible`, try `Can't get my head around this one`

Comment: @kvb You're right. `let z = new Something<OpenXmlElement, OpenXmlElement>()` works

Comment: @Guy. For sure. I was thinking `new Something<string, seq<string>>()` ... which won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

type Node<'a> () =
    let getEmptyEnumerator () = Seq.empty<Node<'a>>.GetEnumerator ()
    interface IEnumerable<Node<'a>> with
        member this.GetEnumerator () = getEmptyEnumerator ()
        member this.GetEnumerator () =
            getEmptyEnumerator () :> System.Collections.IEnumerator
```

Instead of returning the empty sequence, you could implement this class to return a sequence of child nodes. I called this type `Node<'a>`, because it's a fairly idiomatic way to model a tree (or a graph) in C#.

Use:

```
> let smth = Something<string, Node<int>> ();;    
val smth : Something<string,Node<int>>

> smth.x;;
val it : int = 42
```

Answer (score 4):

```
type T() =
    interface seq<T> with
        member this.GetEnumerator() = ([] :> seq<T>).GetEnumerator()
        member this.GetEnumerator() = ([] :> seq<T>).GetEnumerator() :> System.Collections.IEnumerator

let z = new Something<string, T>()
```